# Can I use nested do while loop in C for this?

Tags: c

I am tasked with creating a simple program for a train schedule. I need to have a user input how many trains will be running and how many times the trains will run for the day. For each run I need to tell 1 train at a time to go and the others to standby until they have all traveled. I'm trying to use a nested do while loop to achieve this but not having much luck. Is this possible or am I going about it wrong from the start?

If the user inputs 2 trains will run 2 times my output will read:
Train 1 go. All other trains standby.
Train 2 go. All other trains standby.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int numTrains = 0;
    int timeBlocks = 0;
    int numRuns = 1;
    int timeBlocksran = 0;

    printf("How many trains will be running today?\n");
    scanf("%d", &numTrains);

    printf("How many times will the trains run today?\n");
    scanf("%d", &timeBlocks);
    printf("OK. There will be %d trains running %d times today. Let's get them started. All Aboard.\n", numTrains, timeBlocks);
    do
    {
        timeBlocksran++;
        printf("Time Block %d\n", timeBlocksran);
        do
        {
            printf("Train %d go. All other trains standby.\n", numRuns);
            numRuns++;
        } while (numRuns <= numTrains);
    } while (timeBlocksran <= timeBlocks);

    return 0;
}
```

If the user inputs 2 trains will run 2 times I want my output to read: 
TIME BLOCK 1
Train 1 go. All other trains standby.
Train 2 go. All other trains standby.
TIME BLOCK 2
Train 1 go. All other trains standby.
Train 2 go. All other trains standby.

Comment: You need to reset `numRuns` to 1 before starting the inner loop. I'd recommend using `for` loops for this, it makes it much simpler to read and understand in my opinion. You should also try to keep both loops either one based or zero based, it's confusing now because the order of how you print/increment is reversed between the two loops. Again, for loops would help that.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Ninja. I've emailed my teacher for a week with no response. So you would do away with the do while loops altogether and replace them with for loops? I haven't used them much so apologies or how simple this may be to you. Am I at least getting warm?

for(numRuns=0;numRuns<numTrains;numRuns++)
  {
      printf("Train %d go. All other trains standby.\n", numRuns);
  }

Comment: Yeah, something like that, and print `numRuns + 1` if you want it to be 1,2,3,etc.

Comment: This seemed to accomplish the output my teacher requested. I appreciate your help with the for loop Ninja.
while(timeBlocksran<timeBlocks)
  {
     printf("Time Block %d\n",timeBlocksran+1);
     timeBlocksran++;
     for(numRuns=0;numRuns<numTrains;numRuns++)
        {

            printf("Train %d go. All other trains standby.\n", numRuns+1);
    }
  }